# when to initialize vue and vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Recently I design web that user was separated into "user"/"admin" two roles to login.
Different role would login same page but see the different buttons and functions.

`MainPage.vue` is the container so I call ajax "/init" to get user info and then commit to Vuex store.
Then `Content.vue` is the child page inside `MainPage.vue`. It would show different buttons by `$store.state.user` message.

However, I would like to call different api in `mounted` stage inside `Content.vue` according to user's role.
But the role would not be prepared which is commited by ajax called "/init" at this stage.

The overall flow is
// MainContent.vue

```
beforeCreate: async function () {
            await axios.post('/init').then(response => {
                if(response && response.data && response.data.data){
                    this.$store.commit("login", response.data.data)   
                }
            })
        }
```

// Content.vue

```
mounted: async function() {
    try {
      console.log(this.$store, this.$store.state.user, this.$store.getters.isAdmin)
      // no value here 
}
```

I have check the vue component lifecycle and saw `beforeCreate` of parent would be called before `mounted` of child.
Would lifecycle methods call in order even they are async function?
How should I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could delay the initialization of the `Content` component until the `user` state becomes available in Vuex by attaching a `v-if` directive to the `Content` component. Just make sure to initialize `user` with `null` in the Vuex state.

```
<!-- MainPage.vue -->
<template>
  <Content v-if="$store.state.user" />
</template>
```

Now `this.$store.state.user` and everything that depend on it should be available from `Content` component's `mounted` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 1):

Your component lifecycle will not be a dependable way to handle this case since you're using an async call to fetch the user data. I would suggest displaying a loading state overlay and using `mapGetters` to access the store. This will provide a reactive mechanism for you to know when the user data is available. Below is a general idea for a single file component:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        getLoggedInUser: 'GET_LOGGED_IN_USER',
        getIsUserAdmin: 'GET_IS_USER_ADMIN',
    })
}

....

<template>
    <content-overlay v-if="!getLoggedInUser">
         Loading...
    </content-overlay>

    ....
    <button v-if="getIsUserAdmin">Admin Button</button>
    <button v-if="!getIsUserAdmin">Regular User Button</button>

</template>
```